# How to exclude symbolic link in rsync/rsnapshot

Tags: rsync, backup, rsnapshot

I am using `rsnapshot` to manage my backups. The file `/home/foo/bar` is a symbolic link to a folder, and I want to exclude it. The `--exclude` option does not work, because if the pattern ends with a `/` then it will only match a directory, not a symlink.

How could I do this?

The `rsync` man page says:

> if the pattern ends with a `/` then it will only  match  a  directory,
>   not a regular file, symlink, or device.

So what I'm asking is: how can I exclude from `rsnapshot` a symbolic link to a folder?

If the link is `/home/foo/bar`, which of the following config lines is the right one?

```
exclude /home/foo/bar/

exclude /home/foo/bar

exclude /home/foo/bar**

exclude /home/foo/bar***
```

This is the config file that I'm using now:

```
config_version  1.2
snapshot_root   /media/satellite/rsnapshot/

cmd_cp      /bin/cp
cmd_rm      /bin/rm
cmd_rsync   /usr/bin/rsync
cmd_logger  /usr/bin/logger

retain      hourly  6
retain      daily   7
retain      weekly  4

verbose     2
loglevel    3

lockfile    /var/run/rsnapshot.pid

exclude /home/roberto/media/
exclude /home/roberto/media
exclude /home/roberto/media**
exclude /home/roberto/media***

backup  /home/      localhost/
backup  /etc/       localhost/
backup  /usr/local/ localhost/
backup  /var/www/   localhost/
```

Where `/home/roberto/media` is a symlink to `/media`, which is a directory

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Why would the pattern end with a slash? What's wrong with `--exclude=/bar` (assuming that your source is `/home/foo`)?

Comment: Well, neither --exclude /home/foo/bar nor --exclude /home/foo/bar/ are working

Comment: What command line are you using, and if applicable what configuration file? Copy-paste them into your question.

Comment: Ok, now I have in my configuration file the following lines: 
    exclude /home/roberto/media/
    exclude /home/roberto/media
    exclude /home/roberto/media**
    exclude /home/roberto/media*** --- One of them is the right one, the directory is not copied anymore

Comment: Copy-paste the complete configuration file into your question. We can't help you if you hide crucial information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you set `rsync_short_args` or `rsync_long_args` in the configuration file for `rsnapshot`, you'll use `rsync -a` to perform the copy.

The default action for `rsync -a` is to copy a symlink as a symlink, and to ignore the target of the symlink. (Obviously, if the target of the symlink is within your source file tree it will get copied, but that's because of its position not because it's the target of an included symlink.)

If you want to exclude the symlink itself, you just need to reference it in an `exclude` line:

```
exclude /foo/bar
```

I've not included the leading `/home` because that's the root of your source tree and filters are always based on the root of the source.